# Azure Data Factory Only Retrieve New Blob files from Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-factory

I am currently copying blob files from an Azure Blob storage to an Azure SQL Database. It is scheduled to run every 15 minutes but each time it runs it repeatedly imports all blob files. I would rather like to configure it so that it only imports if any new files have arrived into the Blob storage. One thing to note is that the files do not have a date time stamp. All files are present in a single blob container. New files are added to the same blob container. Do you know how to configure this?

Comment: Are you able to control the naming convention of the files uploaded into blob storage?

Comment: The file name starts with "panda_" for example "panda_20160314T1122_001171_0A0B616D"

Answer (score 2):

I'd preface this answer with a change in your approach may be warranted...

Given what you've described your fairly limited on options.  One approach is to have your scheduled job maintain knowledge of what it has already stored into the SQL db.  You loop over all the items within the container and check if it has been processed yet.

The container has a ListBlobs method that would work for this.  Reference:  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

```
foreach (var item in container.ListBlobs(null, true))
{
   // Check if it has already been processed or not
}
```

Note that the number of blobs in the container may be an issue with this approach.  If it is too large consider creating a new container per hour/day/week/etc to hold the blobs, assuming you can control this.

Comment: is there a way to do this using the JSON properties of Datasets or Pipeline? The idea is to avoid introducing custom code

Comment: If you are dealing with only one blob container then custom code is the only way I am aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Please use CloudBlobContainer.[ListBlobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx)(null, true, [BlobListingDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails.aspx).Metadata) and check CloudBlob.[Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.properties.aspx).[LastModified](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.blobproperties.lastmodified.aspx) for each listed blob.

Comment: This works but requires you to fetch each blob's properties one by one.  Again the number of blobs in the container would determine the feasibility of this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a copy activity, I would use a custom DotNet activity within Azure Data Factory and use the Blob Storage API (some of the answers here have described the use of this API) and Azure SQL API to perform your copy of only the new files.

However, with time, your blob location will have a lot of files, so, expect that your job will start taking longer and longer (after a point taking longer than 15 minutes) as it would iterate through each file every time.

Can you explain your scenario further? Is there a reason you want to add data to the SQL tables every 15 minutes? Can you increase that to copy data every hour? Also, how is this data getting into Blob Storage? Is another Azure service putting it there or is it an external application? If it is another service, consider moving it straight into Azure SQL and cut out the Blob Storage.

Another suggestion would be to create folders for the 15 minute intervals like hhmm. So, for example, a sample folder would be called '0515'. You could even have a parent folder for the year, month and day. This way you can insert the data into these folders in Blob Storage. Data Factory is capable of reading date and time folders and identifying new files that come into the date/time folders.

I hope this helps! If you can provide some more information about your problem, I'd be happy to help you further.

Comment: We can increase the copy activity timings to hourly basis. However, my question is if your files are not in the datetime folder structure then is it possible for the copy activity to pull only the new files? For example like Stream Analytics does. It does not matter whether folder structure is in datetime format with SAS you can have all files in one Blob container and SAS figures out when the new files arrive. I know you get a lot of flexibility when you go down the C# API route. But we are trying to avoid custom code as much as possible.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way to identify new files without either putting them in date/time folders or using custom code. If you don't mind me asking, how are the files landing in Blob Storage to begin with? Is it using some other service in Azure?